# ivy doesn't download jar from remote after local

Tags: java, maven, ant, build, ivy

I configured ivy to go first maven local repo then remote. But something is going wrong! (By the way, im working with snapshots)

1. If ivy cache doesn't exist, ivy first checks maven local repo and then remote to get required jars. Everything is fine.
2. If ivy cache exists, ivy just checks local repo! It doesn't check remote! I have 2 problem here:

   - If I change something in maven project and install it to local repo of maven, ivy still gets the jar from its cache, not in local repo of maven.
   - Even worse, it doesn't get any jar in remote if requsted jars in ivy cache.

#### ivysettings.xml

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain_resolver"/>

  <credentials host="localhost"
               realm="Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager"
               username="username" passwd="password"/>

  <property name="nexus.repo" value="url here"/>
  <property name="nexus-public" value="http://${nexus.repo}:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"/>
  <property name="m2-pattern"   value="${user.home}/.m2/repository/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/[module]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]"/>

  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain_resolver">
      <ibiblio name="nexus" m2compatible="true" root="${nexus-public}"/>
      <filesystem name="local" m2compatible="true">
        <artifact pattern="${m2-pattern}"/>
        <ivy pattern="${m2-pattern}"/>
      </filesystem>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>

</ivysettings>
```

#### Related ant tasks

```
<target name="ivy-download" unless="offline">
    <mkdir dir="${ivy.dir}"/>
    <get src="${repo_public}/org/apache/ivy/ivy/${ivy.ver}/ivy-${ivy.ver}.jar" dest="${ivy.jar}" usetimestamp="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="ivy-install" depends="ivy-download">
    <path id="ivy.lib.path">
      <fileset file="${ivy.jar}"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef resource="org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant" classpathref="ivy.lib.path"/>
    <ivy:settings file="ivysettings.xml" />
  </target>

  <target name="lib.get">
    <mkdir dir="${lib.dir}"/>
    <ivy:retrieve type="jar" conf="lib" pattern="${lib.dir}/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
  </target>

  <target name="ivy.lib.get" depends="ivy-install" if="${skipClean}">
      <antcall target="lib.get" />
    </target>

  <target name="ivy.clean.lib.get" depends="ivy-install" unless="${skipClean}">
    <ivy:cleancache/>
    <antcall target="lib.get" />
  </target>
```

How can I check

- First, local repo and if there is a change, download from local repo
- Then, remote and if there is a change, download from remote

And there is one more possible situation here which is, if there is a change in remote and local at the same time, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Ivy has a local cache dedicated to that purpose. Improving performance by avoiding repeated download of the same artifact. Maven, on the other hand, uses its local repository as a cache (Ivy keeps these concepts separate).

The one operational problem with caches is that over time they become dirty, especially when sharing "integration" or "snapshot" builds.

For this reason I suggest you stop pointing ivy at the Maven local cache for the following reasons:

1. You're creating a strong dependency between two different build technologies.
2. You're caching a cache, rather than caching a repository.... It's a false economy, due to the risk of dirty caches.

My suggestion is simplify everything by introducing a Maven repository manager like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), in order to both cache files from Maven Central and host artifacts shared between project builds.

Comment: I'm using nexus, but nexus gets a snapshot when you deploy. In the case of  installing the snapshot to local repo in order to see difference of your code before deploying, ivy will not get from local(in my case), so you have to deploy. And unfortunately I have to use ivy to comminicate with nexus! Of course I would prefer just maven but it is not the case!

Comment: @AdemIlhan Let Maven publish snapshots to Nexus and let Ivy pull them from Nexus. Ivy has a useful "latest.integration" dynamic revision feature, which only works when retrieving from a Maven repository. (The ibiblio resolver can intepret the special metadata associated with Maven snapshots). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8524755/resolve-ivy-dependency-version-order/8527528#8527528 . Please don't dismiss the idea that Maven's local repository is really a cache! It was never meant to be a true repo. Nexus should be your integration point.